# Argc and Argv in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, argv, argc

I written the following script which gets name of a file and then assemble and link the file. But it doesn't work. What is the problem with it?

```
EXPECTED_ARGS=2


if [ $# -ne $EXPECTED_ARGS ]
then
        echo "[+] Assembling with Nasm."
        nasm -f elf32 $1 -o $1.o

        echo "[+] Linking ..."
        ld $1.o -o $1

        echo "[+] Done!" 

else
        printf  "\nInvalid number of arguments, please check the inputs and try again\n"

fi;
```

When I run it without passing any args, it doesn't shows following error:

```
printf  "\nInvalid number of arguments, please check the inputs and try again\n"
```

Comment: First of all, you must reverse the logic of your `if...then...else` construct. Besides, contrary to the C convention, in bash `$0` doesn't count as an argument, thus `EXPECTED_ARGS` must be 1 in your script

Comment: I set it to 1 but nothing changed.

Comment: You must also reverse your `if ... then ... else` statement (i.e. print an error when the actual count of arguments is not equal to the expected count of arguments, and do the job otherwise)

Comment: -ne is not equal... you swapped the conditions.
if [ $# -eq $EXPECTED_ARGS ] ....

Comment: From my perspective, looking for Bash's ARGC equivalent (with Google) (IE `$#` or `ARGC=$(( $# ))`), the question linked to as the original of the "duplicate" TOTALLY DOESN'T ANSWER that. Making me want to improve the  answers here, yet I cannot.

Answer (score 2):

Define a variable: `ARGC=$#`

and your if statement will look like

```
if [ $ARGC -ne $MAX_ARGS ]; then
```

Legend:

- `-ne` = not equal
- `-gt` = greater than
- `-eq` = equal to